# Zend framework 2 access route in other file then conroller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How can I get the url of a specific route in a file that is neither a controller, modell or view? It is a basic php file. I need this in order to make static js variables with the url of my routes

Comment: If it's just a standalone PHP file, outside of ZF, it won't have an equivalent ZF route. Where is the file located?

Comment: is this file included inside the zf loop or its access with a direct url and standalone ?

Comment: You could define a rewrite rule for it in the vhost file? Or, a brute approach, check the request uri and short-circuit the app in index.php  before even initialising ZF2